how to kill a loop without killing the running process
I have a loop like this running in the background. At some point, I want to stop the loop from going to the next iteration, but I want the current process to continue running until it completes. What should I do?
cat $mani |
while read pref;do
  sh myscript.sh $pref
done &


Check in the loop whether a specific file exists and if so, end the loop with a break. To end the loop, you only need to touch the file.

You could run the loop in a subshell, then kill that process.

Since you're running the loop in the background, it's already in a subshell. The script doesn't wait for the loop to finish.

Aside: This is a Useless Use of Cat. You can use done < "$mani". Also, remember to quote all your variables.

What is "the current process" that you want to avoid killing?  Do you mean an execution of sh myscript.sh $pref?  Or the shell from which you launched the pipeline? Or something else?

Are you sure you want to run myscript.sh using sh instead of bash?

@JohnBollinger Hi, yes i'd like to keep the sh myscript.sh $pref running but kill the loop, prevent it from going to the next. iteration

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What are the specific criteria where you will determine whether you want the myscript.sh to continue running but the loop to stop? Generally you will achieve this by a loop counter or by sending some information back from the process that you call via the loop, but without more information we can't really provide a thorough solution.


I have a loop like this running in the background

Looping commands such as while are built into the shell.  They don't run on their own, rather, they run in the context of a shell process.

I want to stop the loop from going to the next iteration, but I want the current process to continue running until it completes.

... where, you clarified in comments, "the current process" is one execution of sh myscript.sh $pref performed in the loop body.  That's not especially problematic, because that command will launch a separate sh process, independent of its parent except inasmuch as the parent will wait for it to terminate before continuing.
There are at least two general approaches to the problem:

Add an additional condition to the while, that tests some characteristic of the environment, such as whether a specific file exists.  For example, you might use the existence of the input file:
while [[ -e "$mani" ]] && read pref; do
  sh myscript.sh $pref
done < "$mani" &

You could then request the loop to terminate after the current iteration by deleting the file whose name is stored in $mani.  Possible drawbacks of this approach include

control does not pass out of the loop until the current iteration completes
the loop could be prevented from terminating after all by creating a new file of the same name before its absence is noticed


Send a signal, probably SIGTERM, to the shell in which the while is running.  That would be something like
$ kill %job

or
$ kill pid

where job is the appropriate job number or pid is the appropriate process id number.  Possible drawbacks of this approach include:

you need to know or discover the appropriate jobspec or process id
no code following the while loop in the same script will be executed



